# how to obtain undistorted image without interpolation

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I have been trying lot to get an undistorted image without interpolation. But when executed the below code i get some weird image.I am using the function initUndistortRectifyMap which gives the mapx and mapy of type CV_16SC2 later using the convertMaps function i am converting the mapx and mapy to type CV_32FC1.I have been trying to debug the reason but couldnot find anything helpful.

The distorted image
[image]
image after applying undistort without interpolation
[image]

```
int main()
{
 Mat  Cam1MatrixParam, Cam1Distortion;
 Mat cf1;
 cf1=imread("cam1.distort1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  Size imagesize = cf1.size();
FileStorage fs1("cameracalibration.xml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs1["camera_matrix"] >> Cam1MatrixParam;
    fs1["distortion_coefficients"] >> Cam1Distortion;
    Mat R = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F) * 1;
    int width = cf1.cols;
 int height = cf1.rows;
Mat undistorted = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
Mat mapx = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1);
Mat mapy = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1);

initUndistortRectifyMap(Cam1MatrixParam, Cam1Distortion, Cam1MatrixParam, R, imagesize, CV_16SC2, mapx, mapy);
convertMaps(mapx, mapy, mapx, mapy, CV_32FC1, false);

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
        undistorted.at<uchar>(mapy.at<float>(j, i), mapx.at<float>(j, i)) = cf1.at<uchar>(j, i);
        }
    }
    imwrite("cam1.undistortimage.png", undistorted);

}
```

image with this version of code 
                                                                       undistorted.at(j, i) = cf1.at(mapy.at(j, i), mapx.at(j, i));
[image]

image with undistort function(remap with nearest interpolation)
[image]

Comment: maybe you can use cv::remap with CV_INTER_NN to choose nearest pixel instead of interpolation?

Comment: Ya. thanks I have already done that since the nearest interpolation is twice faster than linear interpolation.

Comment: so what else do you expect if you talk about "no interpolation"?

Comment: I feel the interpolation takes time, my goal is to optimize execution time. Now the nearest interpolation does like the apart from mapping real pixels of distort and undistort image, even the neighbouring pixels are assigned with the similar values of it which might consume time. Can I avoid this step that the assigning the neighbouring pixels with similar values.

Comment: Looks like [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38227284/412080) solved your issue. Learn how to use the voting buttons and accept answers, so that people keep answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like instead of undoing the distortion it applies it once more.

`mapx` and `mapy` map from the display coordinates to the photo coordinates.

```
undistorted.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i) = distort.at<cv::Vec3b>(mapy.at<float>(j, i), mapx.at<float>(j, i));
```

You can interpret this code as: for each display coordinate `{j, i}` find its corresponding (distorted) coordinate in the photo and then copy the pixel.

Comment: No, output image still similar to the image i have posted above, which is not the expected output image

Comment: That cannot be true, because the code is different. Unless `mapx` and `mapy` are identify functions.

Comment: So u mean that the mapx and mapy should be identity functions. i,e equal values to get the correct outputed image.

Comment: @Reddy2810 I am saying that if you changed the code as I suggested and the output is still the same, that may mean that `mapx` and `mapy` are identity mappings (which they must not be for the transformation to happen).

Answer (score 1):

you are using color images (cv::Vec3b) so try instead:

```
undistorted.at<cv::Vec3b>(mapy.at<float>(j, i), mapx.at<float>(j, i)) = cf1.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i);
```

maybe combined with the answer of Maxim Egorushkin if undistort map is reverse

Comment: Ya. you r right that i need to consider the (cv::Vec3b) , but when i re-write it has                                                                                                                              undistorted.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i) = cf1.at<cv::Vec3b>(mapy.at<float>(j, i), mapx.at<float>(j, i));                                                                             then i get the similar undistorted image which i generally get from the undistort function with linear interpolation. but i need the image no interpolation.

Comment: can you add the result of your version and the result of cv::undistort with linear interpolation?

Comment: please check the images above I have uploaded it

Comment: can you add your undistortion parameters to reproduce the results?

Comment: camera matrix:    8.800770780435961e+02 0.992599067381656 9.531257486803088e+02 0.
  8.786353237423666e+02 5.069272648474679e+02 0. 0. 1.        distortion coefficients: -0.316992889533314 0.095288556108226
 0.004135906662935 8.747068179335280e-04
  -0.012324941693397

Comment: or is it possible for the mapping only certain part of the image every time. because right now i am trying map the whole distort image to undistort image. Instead is it possible to map only the certain part of the image(certain amount of pixel area in the ROI i.e the red ball) using remap function?

Comment: sure, why not... just iterate over your target area instead of the whole image... easiest would be to use subimages and masks to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116807/discussion-between-reddy2810-and-micka).